# Blackberry - Setting LabelField background color

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, background-color

I want to place several LabelFields with right-aligned text on a MainScreen with an alice blue background.  Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to make that happen.

The best I can do is set my backround to Color.ALICEBLUE on a MainScreen and place LabelFields on the screen (also with a alice blue background).

```
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.ALICEBLUE);
        graphics.clear();
        super.paint(graphics);  
    }
```

and...

```
    LabelField display = new LabelField("", LabelField.FIELD_RIGHT){
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.DIMGRAY);
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.ALICEBLUE);
            graphics.clear();
            super.paint(graphics);  
        }
    };
```

Overriding the MainScreen paint routine gives me my alice blue background, but overriding the LabelFields' paint routines does not seem to be adequate.  The result is a white row, with a alice blue background behind the label text only.  Adding `USE_ALL_WIDTH` corrects the background issue, but I can't right align with `USE_ALL_WIDTH`.

Does anyone know a work around for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In versions <= 4.5 you can create VerticalFieldManager with overrided paint():

```
class BGManager extends VerticalFieldManager {
    public BGManager() {
        super(USE_ALL_HEIGHT|USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.DARKRED);
        graphics.clear();
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
}
```

Then use it on youre screen adding simple LabelField to it:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    BGManager manager = new BGManager();
    public Scr() {
        super();
        add(manager);       
        manager.add(new LabelField("Hello!", FIELD_RIGHT));
        manager.add(new LabelField("This is a test", FIELD_RIGHT));
    }
}
```

In versions >= 4.6 you can use setBackgroud() method for default screen manager:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {  
    public Scr() {
        super();
        VerticalFieldManager manager = 
            (VerticalFieldManager)getMainManager();
        manager.setBackground(
            BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(
                Color.DARKRED));        
        manager.add(new LabelField("Hello!", FIELD_RIGHT));
        manager.add(new LabelField("This is a test", FIELD_RIGHT));
    }
}
```

See [BB KB DB-00131 - How to - Change the background color of a screen](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800256/How_to_-_Change_the_background_color_of_a_screen.html?nodeid=800335&vernum=0)

Comment: Also works great!  Plus this method saves me from having to override the paint method for every LableField I add.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
new LabelField("",LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH | DrawStyle.RIGHT);
```

without overriding the paint method of the LabelField.

Comment: Works great! To get the background color set I actually needed to override the paint method in addition..