# How to use Custom Background image on screen or custom Background colors?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, background-image, color-scheme, branding

I want to change the background screens of one of my Blackberry app and put something like a company logo.

Any idea how to change the background of the screens.
And yes can we also change the color of the title label fields or the buttons?
Can I also change the font color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to code of application it's quite possible.
[Blackberry - background image/animation RIM OS 4.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365727/blackberry-background-image-animation-rim-os-4-5-0)
[Blackberry - Setting LabelField background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257230/blackberry-setting-labelfield-background-color)
[Setting background and font colors for RichTextField, TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431189/setting-background-and-font-colors-for-richtextfield-textfield)