# paintBackground somehow now willing to work

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm trying to create a custom dialog for blackberry...

```
public class cusDialog extends Screen implements FieldChangeListener {

    private cusButtField okButton;

    protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) {   /// this doesn't seem to work.
        graphics.setColor(0x999966);                       /// should I somehow call it?
        graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 12, 12);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 12, 12);
        }

    public cusDialog(String message) {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager(), Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE);
        try {
        FontFamily alphaSansFamily = FontFamily.forName("BBAlpha Serif");
        Font appFont = alphaSansFamily.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 9, Ui.UNITS_pt);
        setFont(appFont);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }
        add(new LabelField(message));
        add(new SeparatorField());
        okButton = new cusButtField("OK", Color.WHITE, Color.LIGHTGREY, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN,Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        okButton.setChangeListener(this);
        add(okButton);
        }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        layoutDelegate(width - 80, height - 80);
        setPositionDelegate(10, 10);
        setExtent(width - 60, Math.min(height - 60, getDelegate().getHeight() + 20));
        setPosition(30, (height - getHeight())/2);
        }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (field == okButton) {
        close();
        }
        }


}
```

yet the "paintBackground" part above doesn't work, i.e. dialog appears on a white background. What do you think might be wrong, should I somehow call this method? Should I put in some other place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago on JDE 4.5. As explained [here (Blackberry-KB)](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800256/How_to_-_Change_the_background_color_of_a_screen.html?nodeid=800335&vernum=0), the code below worked for me.

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics)
{
    graphics.setBackgroundColor(Color.DARKRED);
    graphics.clear();
    super.paint(graphics);
}
```

also, you may want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257230/blackberry-setting-labelfield-background-color) question.